# Adding class to image_tag Ruby

Tags: ruby, helper

Probably something really simple but keep getting syntax errors.. I want to add a class to my image_tag, which is using a helper to form part of a url , though didnt think this would effect where i put my class.

```
<%= image_tag(aws_asset "/assets/img/thumb-1.jpg"), :class => "stock" %>
```

Can anyone see anything obvious that im missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= image_tag(aws_asset("/assets/img/thumb-1.jpg"), :class => "stock") %>
```

**Edit**: Your original code was calling the `image_tag` function with the result of `aws_asset "/assets/img/thumb-1.jpg` as the only parameter (the `:class => "stock"` bit was left out).  The additional parentheses change call to the `image_tag` function to have two parameters, the first being the result of `aws_asset("/assets/img/thumb-1.jpg")` and the second being `:class => "stock"`.

Comment: brilliant, will accept as soon as it lets me, could you explain the extra brackets please